# How do I use Observable.onErrorResumeNext to branch execution and propagate the exception

Tags: rx-java

I have the following chain of observables, A->B, where A creates an entry in a DB and B enqueues a job in a rabbitMQ. What I want to do is having a third one, C, that runs if and only if B throws an exception (it must delete/revert the data entered in the DB). The exception should then be propagated to the caller. I am using onErrorResumeNext, which however seems to work only if I have an explicit (empty) subscriber on it. Note: delegate in the code below returns A and queueSender returns B. Is this right, or is there a better way to do it?

```
public Observable<Long> create(final Message m) {
    return delegate.create(m).flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Long> call(final Long aLong) {
            Observable<Void> observableB = queueSender.observe(aLong)

            observableB.onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<Void>>()    {
                @Override
                public Observable<Void> call(Throwable throwable) {
                    delegate.delete(aLong).toBlockingObservable().single();
                    return null;
                }
            }).subscribe(new VoidSubscriber());

            return timelineObservable.map(new Func1<Void, Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long call(Void aVoid) {
                    return aLong;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to get rid of the VoidSubscriber would be to zip observableB with your timelineObservable. Since onErrorResumeNext() would swallow the error, you would also need to change the onErrorResumeNext() to just doOnError() to propagate the error. Here's the modified code:

```java
public Observable<Long> createOld(final Message m) {
    return delegate.create(m).flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Long> call(final Long aLong) {
            final Observable<Void> observableB =
                    queueSender
                            .observe(aLong)
                            .doOnError(
                                    new Action1<Throwable>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                            delegate.delete(aLong).toBlockingObservable().single();
                                        }
                                    }
                            );

            final Observable<Long> observableTimeline =
                    timelineObservable
                            .map(new Func1<Void, Long>() {
                                @Override
                                public Long call(Void aVoid) {
                                    return aLong;
                                }
                            });

            return Observable
                    .zip(
                            observableB,
                            observableTimeline,
                            new Func2<Void, Long, Long>() {
                                @Override
                                public Long call(Void aVoid, Long aLong) {
                                    return aLong;
                                }
                            }
                    );
        }
    });
}
```